# How to auto inject class text angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textbox

There is a way to auto generate class when user pick for example list in the text editor, i want to auto inject some class to the ul tag before saving to db?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `ng-class`. You will need to set up an ng-model directive to the select box and use ngClass to activate the class name when the expression is met.

The documentation is at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass.

Comment: i think you dont understand me. im using text editor name text angular, and when user want list he click on list icon and the plugin generate behind the scene the html. i want to be able to intercept this html and inject my classes.

Comment: Oh wow, sorry I didn't get that. I'm looking at it now, I think I'll give it a try.